# How to call a private void keypress event handler from client side using C# or ASP.net to allow only numbers into textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I've never learned either ASP.net or C# and yet I'm trying to create a textbox using ASP.net that only allows numbers to be entered. I'm using the following code to define my textbox in Default.aspx:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="StudentNo" 
       autopostback="true"      
       OnTextChanged="StudentNo_KeyPress" 
       style="margin-left:20px; width:70px;"/>
```

The `OnTextChanged` however isn't calling anything from the server side page (Default.aspx.cs) and here is the code I'm using for that:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
...
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms

private void StudentNo_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
   if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar)
      && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar)
      && e.KeyChar != '.')
   {
      e.Handled = true;
   }
}
```

I've tried to give only the relevant bits with correct indentation but I fear it isn't going to work. I'm sorry if this is a really basic question, but as I said, I've never coded in either of these languages. I'm not allowed to use JavaScript or AJAX, just C# and ASP.net.

Any suggestions or alternative solutions would be fantastic. I've already tried using `RangeValidator`, `RegularExpressionValidator`, `RequiredFieldValidator` and `CustomValidator`, none of which were any use whatsoever.

Thanks in advance, any help is hugely appreciated. If you require more information, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were headed down the correct path with ASP.NET validation server controls.

Use RegularExpressionValidator this way:

```
<asp:TextBox id="txtNumber" runat="server" />

<asp:RegularExpressionValidator id="regexValidator" runat="server"
    ControlToValidate="txtNumber" ErrorMessage="You must enter a number"
    ValidationExpression="^\d+$" />
```

and if you want to require a number to be entered, then add this one too:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="reqValidator" runat="server" 
    ControlToValidate="txtNumber" ErrorMessage="You must enter a number" />
```

Note that the "ControlToValidate" attribute must be set to the control that you are validating.  For your example the value would be "StudentNo"

Comment: thanks for your help. Unfortunately, once i've implemented this code, I type into the textbox (whilst in debug mode on Visual Studio 2010 in firefox) and nothing happens. I've tried typing letters and numbers and nothing is happening except that everything gets entered into txtNumber...do i need to call the validators in via c#? There is no error message either :( thanks again for your help

Comment: actually, something that is working is that upon submitting the textbox with alphabetic characters, it comes up with the error code. Is there a way to call the validation `OnTextChanged`?

Comment: It is working as ASP.NET designed.  ASP.NET is a server-side control-based framework.  So those validators are working on the server, when you submit.  What you are asking for is client-side validation, which is accomplished via JavaScript and Ajax which you stated you were not allowed to use.  OnTextChanged is still an event which is handled on the server and is only fired when you change focus away from the text box so it does not validate every character entered, just when you click on something other than the textbox.

Comment: Think:  Client = local browser, Server = web server serving up the response from the URL you typed into the browser.  ASP.NET controls (asp:TextBox, etc.) are server-side and therefore a round trip to the web server must happen for the page to change.  The C# is on the server and is specifying what it will return for the  response.

Comment: So you cannot implement client-side validation using only ASP.NET/C#.  You need to use JavaScript/Ajax/etc.

Comment: yes it does thank you. Though unfortunately it does not solve my problem haha